# Rails: Accessing instance variable from not inline JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, instance-variables

I have this code in a **.html.erb** file:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<script>
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function(response) {
          send_fb_like();
      }
  );
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
      function(response) {
          send_fb_unlike();
      }
  );
  function send_fb_like()
  {
    var business_name = '<%= @consumer.name %>';
    alert("You liked"+consumer_name);
  }
  function send_fb_unlike()
  {
    var business_name = '<%= @consumer.name %>';
    alert("You unliked"+consumer_name);
  }

</script>
```

This is working correctly, and I can access the **@consumer.name** correctly.  However, if I change this to:

Where facebook_consumer.js looks like this:

```
$(function(){

FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
          function(response) {
              send_fb_like();
          }
      );
      FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
          function(response) {
              send_fb_unlike();
          }
      );
      function send_fb_like()
      {
        var business_name = '<%= @consumer.name %>';
        alert("You liked"+consumer_name);
      }
      function send_fb_unlike()
      {
        var business_name = '<%= @consumer.name %>';
        alert("You unliked"+consumer_name);
      }


});
```

It will dump this:

You liked `<%= @consumer.name %>`. I have tried saving the file as js.erb, but then it seems it doesn't know what @consumer is.

Any thoughts on what is the best approach?

Comment: Sometimes I create an hash on the markup just to put some values like these, so the javascript from the reference *file* will be able to access.. I don't really know whether this is a good or bad idea tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create an app-wide JS object to store values you need. At the top of the page, you can add elements to this object, and they will be available to your linked scripts.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app = app || {}
    app.keyName1 = "<%= @variable1 %>";
    app.keyName2 = "<%= @variable2 %>";
</script>
```

Comment: How would I access the attributes of @variable? I have tried @variable.to_json.html_safe but I keep getting 'undefined', even though I can see the json object in the console.

Comment: is `@variable` an array? If it is, you'll need to loop through it somehow and assign keys and values to the `app` object. Not very elegant, I'll admit.

Comment: Variable is an object from a Model. In the console, after doing to_json (variable = @variable.to_json)I can see the object as { "key" : "attribute",...} but I try to access with variable.key and I get undefined >(.

Comment: Hmm, would it work if you tried it this way: `app = "{'<%= @variable.to_json %>'}";`

Answer (score 1):

You can't inline Ruby code into .js files.  If you want to use Ruby code, you need to create a .js.erb file and then render a partial inside of that.

```
# controller
render :partial => "/path/to/js/partial.js.erb"

# inside your JS partial
# you can use <%= @consumer.name %> freely in this file
# and then add the line below to render your normal html.erb file
$("#reviews").append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/path/to/partial.html.erb' )) %>");
```